# how to create roles in asp.net with createuser control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a site that have `Createuser` page and i put the asp.net `createuser` in it.my site have `roles` i.e a user that create it's account must have a role. But create user control only create user and can not construct it's role so new user doesn't have any role how can i give role to new users?

Comment: You sure have a lot of crates. It leaves me wondering if those are actual spelling errors.

Comment: @ChaosPandion - it's a common mistake I think

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do so - see [How To: Use Role Manager in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647401.aspx#paght000013_step3), step 3 (old but this hasn't changed much since).

The options listed are:

- Using the ASP.NET Web Site Configuration Tool
- Using the AzMan Administrator MMC Snap-In
- Using SQL Scripts
- Using the Role Management APIs

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain how I solved this issue
You've two things here:
one is creating the role and inserting into the database. For this use

```
Roles.CreateRole(txtRole.Text);
```

The other thing you've is once user is created you want to make the user a member of some role. This can be achieved by adding a new wizardstep to the CreateUserWizard control in between the SignUp and complete wizard.

In this new wizard put two listboxes. and put add/remove buttons between them.

Populate the first listbox with available roles (can be done in the `CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser` event)

```
  ListBox1.DataSource=Roles.GetAllRoles();
  ListBox1.DataBind();
```

Let the add button add selected roles to the second listbox. 
Finally, in the `CreateUserWizard1_FinishButtonClick` event add the user to the roles

```
 foreach(ListItem it in ListBox2.Items)
    if(it.Selected)
      Roles.AddUserToRole(CreateUserWizard1.UserName,it.Text);
```

Hope it helps !